# Mounting lvm after fstab entry is not creating SElinux labels in the new lvm

Tags: linux, selinux

On RHEL8, I created an lvm with ext4 filesystem. Added it to `/etc/fstab` but when I use `mount -av`, I get the following error:

```
You just mounted an file system that supports labels which does not
       contain labels, onto an SELinux box. It is likely that confined
       applications will generate AVC messages and not be allowed access to
       this file system.  For more details see restorecon(8) and mount(8).
/lvext4                  : successfully mounted
```

If I create a file inside `/lvext4`, it's SELinux context is `unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 file1`

Same error when I mount an XFS lvm.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is why am I getting the SELinux error, why aren't new files correctly labeled and is it the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are receiving is not an error. It's a warning that there is no SELinux label on the file system. An error would have prevented it from mounting but that didn't happen as is indicated by the message:

```
/lvext4                  : successfully mounted
```

RHEL and most other distributions don't automatically apply SELinux contexts to file systems from the start and instead leave that up to whoever is managing the system.

If you plan to have an application access data on the LV, then you need to alter the context to allow it to do so via `chcon` and the proper switches depending on what the application needs to do.

If that isn't the case, then you don't need to do anything and can just ignore the warning. As the LV is in /etc/fstab, then it will mount during boot and you won't see it anyway.